# ElasticSearch autocomplete

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch

I have got four documents with a field named "fullname".

Documents:

- Abigail Harrison
- Abigale Hardison
- Abilene Havington
- Abilene-Havington

I would like to make an autocompleter for this field. Some examples:

**Search:** "Abi"
**Result:** "Abigail Harrison", "Abigale Hardison", "Abilene Havington"

**Search:** "Abig"
**Result:** "Abigail Harrison", "Abigale Hardison"

**Search:** "Abigail Har"
**Result:** "Abigail Harrison", "Abigale Hardison"

**Search:** "Abilene Hav"
**Result:** "Abilene Havington", "Abilene-Havington"

**Search:** "Har"
**Result:** "Abigail Harrison", "Abigale Hardison"

I do not want something like this: (!)

**Search:** "iga"
**Result:** "Abigail Harrison", "Abigale Hardison"

Whitespaces and hyphens should be ignored and I'd like to have all generated tokens lowercase, so the search query should not be case-sensitive.

My ES settings are the following.

```
{
"mappings": {
    "person": {
        "properties": {
            "fullname": {
                "index": "analyzed",
                "index_analyzer": "autocomplete",
                "search_analyzer": "standard",
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
},
"settings": {
    "index": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "edgengram"
                    ],
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "edgengram": {
                    "max_gram": 50,
                    "min_gram": 3,
                    "type": "edgeNGram"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: And what seems to be the problem? What is happening that you do not expect?

Answer (score 1):

While indexing you should use a standard tokenizer along with lowercase, asciifolding, suggestion_shingle, edgengram and while searching use a keyword analyzer.

Try using something like this:

```
"index":{
"analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding",
                "suggestions_shingle",
                "edgengram"
            ]
        }
    },
    "filter": {
        "suggestions_shingle": {
            "type": "shingle",
            "min_shingle_size": 2,
            "max_shingle_size": 5
        },
        "edgengram": {
            "type": "edgeNGram",
            "min_gram": 2,
            "max_gram": 30,
            "side": "front"
        }
    }
}
}

"mappings": {
    "person": {
        "properties": {
            "fullname": {
                "index": "analyzed",
                "index_analyzer": "autocomplete",
                "search_analyzer": "keyword",
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then try searching using a **match query**. It should solve your problem.

Thanks